# CGContextSetRGBFillColor always set the color to black

Tags: objective-c, geometry, drawrect

I have a UIView that draws a circle, this is my code.

I'm trying to set the color to "light red", but it always end up black no matter the values I put in CGContextSetRGBFillColor.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(20, 100, 9, 9));
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 255.0/255.0, 115.0/255.0, 155.0/255.0, 0.7);

    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(20, 100, 9, 9));
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 255.0/255.0, 115.0/255.0, 155.0/255.0, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the fill color *before* you draw the shape. And if you want to stroke, you have to set the *stroke* color.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 255.0/255.0, 115.0/255.0, 155.0/255.0, 0.7);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(20, 100, 9, 9));

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 255.0/255.0, 115.0/255.0, 155.0/255.0, 0.7);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(20, 100, 9, 9));
}
```